# gpio write doesn't work

Tags: gpio

I just starting with Raspberry PI and I have first problem with understanding what's happen with GPIO.
I have installed wiringPI and after call readall GPIO. 7 is set to 1 and I can't change it to 0 by `gpio write 7 0`.

Here is the screenshoot:
[image]

Changing value via Pigs also doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with sudo?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I tried with different pins and it doesn't work with wPi 0 too. But works with wPi: 2 and 3 (without sudo).

Comment: What does pigs report? (sudo pigpiod then pigs w 4 0 r 4 w 4 1 r 4)

Comment: @joan - I'm unable to install pigs. After calling make it hang on this: `gcc -03 -Wall   -c -o pigpio.o pigpio.c`.

Comment: It probably isn't hanging.  The compilation of pigpio.c takes three minutes on a Pi.  Be patient.

Comment: @joan - Indeed compilation takes few minutes. Some progres bar would be welcome. Unfortunately pigs return the same result.

Comment: It would be impossible to have a progress bar with a compiler call because it is impossible for the compiler to know how much work is left to do.

Comment: Two possibilities, 1) the gpio is bust, 2) the gpio is connected to something which is forcing it high.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
su root
```

You will need the root password.  `sudo` alone is a PITA for the next few steps because of redirection.

```
cd /sys/class/gpio
```

If you see a `gpio7` directory there already, skip the next step.

```
echo 7 > export
```

There should now be a `gpio7` directory.

```
cd gpio7
echo out > direction
echo 0 > value
cat value
```

The last command should report `0`.  If not, as joan says, something mysterious is going on with the hardware.

Comment: wiringPi has been updated and should now work on a Pi 2.  pigpio does not currently work on a Pi 2 (in fact it will hang the machine).